# UIButton Background Image Does not Fill Button Frame

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

I have a button where I must mimic the style of a `UISegmentedControl`. I have the image I want to use as the button's background image, but it does not fill the button's rectangle.

I would like button's dimensions to be h=30, w=100, and I have the original image where scaling image before I add it to Interface Builder is not an issue. If I scale the image (in GIMP) to exact dimensions I want (for retina and non-retina), I still get the same issue.

[image]

How would I go about getting the background image of the button to fill the buttons's rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was much simpler than I thought, keeping in mind my meager photoshop skills. There was no need to dig through the properties on the `UIButton`. The image I was provided had a transparent background that was larger than the visible image. It was a simple matter of cropping the image to only the visible portions.

Another lesson in "the simplest solution is usually the best."

Comment: I spent so long looking for the same thing. Thanks for posting the answer!